# Objective C: Autolayout - NSLayoutAttributeBottom no working

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I'm trying to make a flexible view with various subview. I got that working before with autolayout without any problems. Now when I add NSLayoutAttributeBottom, nothing happens.

I'm doing this in initWithFrame method:

```
UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

[self addSubview:titleLabel];

[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:titleLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:titleLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:titleLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:titleLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottomMargin multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
```

This has always worked for me and stretched the view correctly. What am I missing?

Comment: The code you pasted should have worked. Check other places. Otherwise, Are you doing any animation like changing frame of view like that?

Comment: Nope. Only difference is that the view is a subview of a subview and everything is added programatically with CGRectZero and autolayout. Everything should work :-/

Comment: Nevermind. The problem was in scrollview. I had to add a content view to it, pin it to the bottom and position the subview in it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in a scroll view. I added UIView as a contentView, added Top, Left, Width and Bottom constraint to it. When a place a subviews into this view, everything works OK.